# Is there a GTK-Theme preview application?

Tags: themes, gtk, development, widgets, layout

is there an Application which lets me preview all the Theme-Widgets at once?

Like in the old Ubuntu-tweak there was some sort of Preview of all Theme-button/slider/progressbar-layouts. But nowadays there isnt.

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

You can just install the **The Widget Factory** with

```
sudo apt-get install thewidgetfactory
```

And run it in your terminal with

```
twf
```

Answer (score 3):

The package has moved and is now called `gtk3-widget-factory`.

```
$ sudo apt install gtk3-widget-factory
$ gtk3-widget-factory
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is "**The Widget Factory**" or its somewhat newer version **PyWF** which is available from here: https://code.activestate.com/pypm/pywf/

Answer (score 1):

You can try widget factory for gtk3

```
sudo apt install gtk-3-examples
gtk3-widget-factory
```